# How to Configure the injection of my IErrorInfoBuilder in AbpBoilerPlate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

Starting from the MVC module-zero-template I defined my `IErrorInfoBuilder` in this way:

```
public class MyErrorInfoBuilder : IErrorInfoBuilder, ISingletonDependency {
    // ...
}
```

and I injected it in the `PreInitialize` method of the `BookingWebApiModule`, the only point the code where the `Register` method does not throw an error:

```
namespace GPSoftware.Booking.Api {
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpWebApiModule), typeof(BookingApplicationModule))]
    public class BookingWebApiModule : AbpModule {

        public override void PreInitialize() {
            IocManager.Register<IErrorInfoBuilder, MyErrorInfoBuilder>();
        }
    // ...
}
```

**My problem is** my custom error builder is not always invoked by the framework in my application. There are some situations (like when a validation error occurs in the input DTO of a AppService method) that continues to invoke the default Abp implementation of the `IErrorInfoBuilder` interface.

I am sure It is a matter of initialization/configuration. But I don't know how and where, in the code, to fix the issue.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5? Which version of ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Comment: @aaron, aspnetboilerplate v5.9, upgraded from v4,11 where the behavior was the same

Comment: Is it ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, it is a ASP.NET MVC 5 application using Jquery and EF 6.1, now upgraded to EF 6.3.

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template)?